# How to mark transactions that are within 15 seconds of eachother with the same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset containing the following columns e.g:

| TerminalID | TransactionDate | TransactionTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 05:49:40 |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 05:49:46 |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 06:20:05 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:15 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:25 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:35 |

and I would like to create a column, which gives a common ID to those transactions made on the same TerminalID and are within 15 seconds of eachother. The example table should end up like this:

| TerminalID | TransactionDate | TransactionTime | CrossID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 05:49:40 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 05:49:46 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | 06:20:05 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:15 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:25 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 03:31:35 | 3 |

The first two tranactions are made on the same terminal within 15 seconds (they get the crossID 1), while the third terminal transactions happened much later (so it gets the crossID 2, and there are no more transactions within 15 seconds on that terminal). The last three transactions are made within 15 seconds of the previous transaction, so even though there are more than 15 seconds between the first and the last transaction on terminal two, they get the same CrossID, because there is a transaction between them that connects them.

I have made some working code in Python using Pandas and Datetime, but my dataset is too big to load with Python, so I'll need to use SQL (which I have only used for very basic queries). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can the 15 minutes span midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 15 minutes does not span midnight, then use lag to get the previous time and sum up a flag when the difference is greater than 15 minutes:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_transactionTime > dateadd(minute, -15, transactionTime) then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by terminalId order by transactionDate, transactionTime) as crossID
from (select t.*,
             lag(transactionTime) over (partition by terminalId, transactionDate order by transactionTime) as prev_transactionTime
      from t
     ) t;
```

If the 15 minute period can pass midnight, then you should really fix the data, so has the date/time in one column.  You can get around that using:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_transactionDateTime > dateadd(minute, -15, transactionDateTime) then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by terminalId order by transactionDateTime) as crossID
from (select t.*,
             lag(v.transactionDateTime) over (partition by t.terminalId order by v.transactionDateTime) as prev_transactionDateTime
      from t cross apply
           (values (convert(datetime, t.transactionDate) + convert(datetime, t.transactionTime))
           ) v(transactionDateTime)
     ) t;
```

SQL Server allows two `datetime` values to be added together, which is probably the simplest way to combine them.

Comment: I'm amazed by the speed you answered my question. The 15 minute period can pass midnight, but interesting to see the difference in the two solutions. I just ran your query, and the column 'CrossID' is the same as the one from my Python code (or atleast for the smaller test data) - Thank you very much!